# H2 CSVRead gives FileNotFoundException

Tags: spring-boot, docker, jpa, h2

I have a Spring Boot application that uses JPA with H2. `data.sql` has the following content:

```sql
INSERT INTO artists
SELECT *
FROM CSVREAD('/usr/local/data/artists.csv’);
```

and that path works locally (though changed to a local directory). However when dockerized with the following image:

```
# Build stage
FROM maven:3.8.6-amazoncorretto-17 AS build
COPY src /home/app/src
COPY pom.xml /home/app
RUN mvn -f /home/app/pom.xml clean package -DskipTests

# Package state
FROM amazoncorretto:17-alpine
COPY --from=build /home/app/target/webusengus-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /usr/local/lib/webusengus.jar
COPY --from=build /home/app/src/main/resources/artists.csv /usr/local/data/artists.csv

EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/usr/local/lib/webusengus.jar”]
```

on startup a `java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /usr/local/data/artists.csv` is thrown, but when exploring the image through `docker export` the file is in `/usr/local/data/artists.csv`

Given that docker is a superuser, I also don’t see how this could relate to file access?

Comment: How are you actually running the container?  (Are there any volume mounts over `/usr/local` that could be hiding the CSV file?)

Comment: I’m using docker compose, and there are no volume mounts added. The docker compose is just frontend, backend, h2 db in one network with static ips.